# Server-Client notifications

Tags: c++, windows

I don't know how to ask correctly, but there is my situation:

I have some server with some address, for example, http://www.somesite1.com. There is php scripts there.
I have desktop application written with C++ (Windows only, no need cross-platform solution).

I need to know about some events from server - server must inform application in some way.
I can have a lot of clients (100 000, for example) at the same time.

The question is how can i do this ?
How can i establish connection from client to server and then receive notifications from server to client (How to inform server about application start and close (connect for receiving notifications and disconnect for dismiss notifications)?)

I found WebSockets, but i can't really understand how to use them in case of php -> C++ ligament.

And i have C++98/03 standard compiler

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Websocket have anything to do with your task: you need standard sockets (and an http library).

Your client should open a socket, connect to the server and communicate with the GET/POST methods. Note that sending data from server to client will probably be a little mess, requiring you to keep a tcp connection alive (for each client).

have a look at this c++ http library: [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

or, if you want to implement the http protocol by yourself using standard socket: [boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Comment: I'm using curl for GET/POST requests to server. Right now i'm sending request every dt secs of time to server and updating my status in such way, but it's not what i need